# Could not see the difference between $a_{n}$ & $a_{n+1}$ is as given

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could not see the difference between $a_{n}$ & $a_{n+1}$ is that what is given in the last line below ..... could anyone explain this for me please?

> [image]

Comment: To see what $a_{n+1}$ is blindly replace $n$ by $n+1$ in the expression for $a_n$. When you take the difference $a_{n+1}-a_n$ lots of terms cancel out and you will be left with just three terms.

Comment: @Nosrati Please take a second look. You will have three terms in $a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Comment: I have done what you said @KaviRamaMurthy but seems there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n=5$. Ignore the square roots and reciprocals and just look at the $n(n+1)$ part.

The terms in $a_n$ start with $5\times 6$ and end with $9\times 10$. There are five terms.

The terms in $a_{n+1}$ start with $6\times 7$ and end with $11\times 12$. There are six terms.

Going from $5$ to $6$ you lose $5\times 6$ and gain $10\times 11$ and $11\times 12$. You gain one more term than you lose.

Does that help to see what is going on for the general $n$?

Comment: yes it is Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

$$\require{cancel}$$
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\cancel{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}}+\cdots+\cancel{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}-\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n)(n+1)}}+\cancel{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}}+\cdots+\cancel{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}}\right)$$